# Cannot call an external file when running JavaScript in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, web-worker

I'm trying to run this in my `index.html`:

```
<script>
var stockfish = new Worker('./js/stockfish.js');

stockfish.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
  console.log(e.data);
});
 
stockfish.postMessage('uci');
</script>
```

But I get the following error:

`Security error: content located at file:///D:/ChessComparator/index.html cannot load data from file:///D:/ChessComparator/js/stockfish.js`.

I cannot run web workers on Chrome and I can't think of another browser to test this on.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution to these sorts of problems is to avoid testing in file URI and other `null` origins.

If you just to get it working, try running `python -m http.server` or `python3 -m http.server` from the source directory to serve the files. Then you can visit `http://localhost:8080` in your browser to view your webpage locally.

Answer (score -2):

i found that it just doesn't work in chrome locally by default. how to get it to work on chrome i don't know, but you can just use safari or firefox

Comment: This is not the point of my question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).